# Blur and Motion Blur augmentation

Tags: tensorflow, deeplab

I am using Deeplabv3+ repository and I would like to know how do you apply Motion Blur and Blur as augmentation. I have a few augmentations already, like random scale (example).

However, I could not find any out of the box solution to apply Motion Blur on tensorflow.
Does anyone know any library or how to build this transformation?

```
def randomly_scale_image_and_label(image, label=None, scale=1.0):
  """Randomly scales image and label.

  Args:
    image: Image with shape [height, width, 3].
    label: Label with shape [height, width, 1].
    scale: The value to scale image and label.

  Returns:
    Scaled image and label.
  """
  # No random scaling if scale == 1.
  if scale == 1.0:
    return image, label
  image_shape = tf.shape(image)
  new_dim = tf.cast(
      tf.cast([image_shape[0], image_shape[1]], tf.float32) * scale,
      tf.int32)

  # Need squeeze and expand_dims because image interpolation takes
  # 4D tensors as input.
  image = tf.squeeze(tf.image.resize_bilinear(
      tf.expand_dims(image, 0),
      new_dim,
      align_corners=True), [0])
  if label is not None:
    label = tf.squeeze(tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(
        tf.expand_dims(label, 0),
        new_dim,
        align_corners=True), [0])

  return image, label
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good library called **albumentations**.

You can have a look here: https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations/blob/master/notebooks/example.ipynb.

I am sure it will be of great usage; it contains all sorts of augmentations, for different use cases(object detection, image segmentation).

Comment: I know that library. However `cv2` requires the image to be converted to a `numpy` array. I was looking for something from tensorflow, like the example I pasted

Comment: I don't understand. Why is there a problem if you have a Numpy array? And even so, why don't you cast the NumPy array to a TF Tensor?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, these libraries were invented for this exact reason: the dl frameworks did not have out of the box solutions for such augmentations.

Comment: Never tried that, but I will try to do that. Do you have something that you used before that could be handy to do this?
I will mark this as solved since it might solve my question. Thank you!

Comment: You could use: tf.convert_to_tensor(my_numpy_array, dtype=tf.float32) (at least in TF 2.0). Your "my_numpy_array" is any image converted by means of augmentation, exactly like in the tutorial I provided to you above.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find direct implementation of motion blur in tensorflow. You have to implement it using `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d`. Looking at the implementation of motion blur from albumentation, you need to create a filter of random size, say `nxn` and then draw a random line on the filter.  Then use that filter to apply depthwise convolution on the image.

For example, motion blur filter for size 5 at 180/0 degree looks like

```
>>> kernel = np.zeros([5,5])                                                                                                                                          
>>> kernel[2] = 0.2                                                                                                                                                   
>>> kernel                                                                                                                                                            
array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

Now applying the filter to `image` (of [height, width, 3])

```
>>> kernel_motion_blur = tf.convert_to_tensor(kernel, tf.float32)
>>> kernel_motion_blur = tf.tile(kernel_motion_blur[..., None, None], [1,1,3,1])
>>> blurred_image = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(image[None], kernel_motion_blur, strides=(1,1,1,1), padding='VALID')
```

Note:  To generate motion blur kernels, you can use `cv2.line` to draw random lines on numpy array